# CDK/CloudFormation Batch Setup NotStabilized Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-batch

I'm trying to set up a simple Batch Compute Environment using a LaunchTemplate, so that I can specify a larger-than-default volume size:

```
 const templateName = 'my-template'

 const jobLaunchTemplate = new ec2.LaunchTemplate(stack, 'Template', {
    launchTemplateName: templateName,
    blockDevices: [ ..vol config .. ] 
  })

 const computeEnv = new batch.CfnComputeEnvironment(stack, 'CompEnvironment', {
    type: 'managed',
    computeResources: {
      instanceRole: jobRole.roleName,
      instanceTypes: [
        InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.C4, InstanceSize.LARGE).toString()
      ],
      maxvCpus: 64,
      minvCpus: 0,
      desiredvCpus: 0,
      subnets: vpc.publicSubnets.map(sn => sn.subnetId),
      securityGroupIds: [vpc.vpcDefaultSecurityGroup],
      type: 'EC2',
      launchTemplate: {
        launchTemplateName: templateName,
      }
    },
  })
```

They both initialize fine when not linked, however as soon as the `launchTemplate` block is added to the compute environment, I get the following error:

```
Error: Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment' with identifier 'compute-env-arn' did not stabilize." (RequestToken: token, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized)
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running into this - check the resource that is being created in the AWS Console - i.e go to aws.amazon.com and refresh the page over and over until you see it created by CF. This gave me a different error message regarding the instance profile not existing (A bit more helpful than the terminal error...)

A simple `CfnInstanceProfile` did the trick:

```
new iam.CfnInstanceProfile(stack, "batchInstanceProfile", {
    instanceProfileName: jobRole.roleName,
    roles: [jobRole.roleName],
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Sam suggested, the best way to get a more informative error message is to **go to the AWS Console of the resource being created (in this case Batch Compute Environments) and try to catch the resource in its create state**.

In my case, the issue had to do with the user data in the launch template I create (upgrading cdk 2.64 -> 2.90 required updating batch alpha constructs and launch templates are defined differently)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error.

But in my case cdk had created subnetGroups list in `cdk.context.json` and was trying to use the same in the CfnComputeEnvironment definition.

The problem was; I was using the default vpc and had manually modified few subnets. and `cdk.context.json` was not updated.

Solved by deleting the `cdk.context.json`

This file was recreated with correct values in next synth.

**Tip for others facing similar problem:**
Don't just rely on the error message; watch closely the Cloud-formation Script that's generated from CDK for the resource.